# Use swagger API to connect server and client side in meteor application

Tags: node.js, api, meteor, swagger

[image]

I'm trying to use swagger API as a connector between Client side and Server Side in my meteor application. I'm trying to do this because then I can use this as a connector to connect mobile application and other third-party applications to my app.
I chose swagger because it has all tool that I need and also because of the security.
Is this approach good for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?

Here is a REST API for Meteor: https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus

Also have a look at this: https://github.com/apinf/restivus-swagger - I haven't tried it, but it might be what you want.

I think this is a good project, and I'm sure a few people would be interested in it

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://github.com/meteor-rest That community is pretty much Restivus & Swagger :)

For existing API try out restivus-swagger.

If you start out by designing Swagger spec, try out generator-restivus, that scaffolds Restivus from swagger spec.

Please open Github issues if any problems, I follow up to help & fix bugs :)